# How can I resolve request not registering during first initialisation in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have an issue with part of my code. I can't show you the whole code but it's a simple website coded in flask/html/css where you choose a date via an input html form, you submit it and it shows it on the "result" page.

My issue is that when you first go on the page and submit a date, you would get an 500 error (`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`). This means that the form has issues with logging the date. To resolve it, you need to go back to the previous page and do it again. Most of the time it works really well but not 100%. Not sure if the issue is in the python code (problem at 1st initialisation). I've tried setting a default date but it doesn't resolve the issue as it would still not register the correct date on first initialisation.

Edit: It happens every once in a while, not only at start

app.py :

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        day = request.values['day']
        data.day = day
        return redirect('/result')
    return render_template('index.html', date=str(date.today()))


@app.route('/result', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def result():
    if request.method == "POST":
        day = request.values['day']
        data.day = day
        return redirect('/result')

    return render_template('result.html', day=data.day)
```

index.html :

```
<form action="{{ url_for("index") }}" method="POST" id="day">
    <div><input type="date" name="day" id="day" required>
        <span class="validity"></span>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" form="day" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure where any `day` value should come from, since you don't have a `name` on your input element. You also have duplicate `id` values (an id should only be used in one location in an HTML document, i.e. it should uniquely identify an element). I also recommend using `request.form` to retrieve POST-ed values instead ( `.values()` will use the value from either the GET argument string or from a POST value). Also, the redirect will not carry over any already POSTed values, and since you haven't included `result.html` - it might simply be that `result.html` differs from `index.html`.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know exactly which line triggers the call to `int`, since neither of your code segments shows that (and where is `data` defined?)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I've adjusted my code.
- The `name` was in the input tag, not sure why it isn't there (editing). I've changed it so it's in the form tag.
- Thanks for the `id` feedback and the `request.form`, I've updated it in my code.
- I take the str from the form and put it in data.day, then I change it to a date using :
```yyyy, mm, dd = date[:4], date[5:7], date[8:10]
    a = datetime(int(yyyy), int(mm), int(dd))``` 
Hence the int issue. I've tried to catch the 500 exeption in a 500.html file that returns the data.day and it's blank. It then doesn't register any date.